# Reputation penalties if someone votes to close a question and it is reopened?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, reputation, vote-to-reopen

I feel that people often downvote or vote for close far too quickly. The quality is something really different in my humble opinion.

- If someone votes to close a question without giving a comment I would detract some points from their reputation.
- If the question is reopened I would detract many points from their  reputation.
- If the question is reopened without any modifies I would detract 50 points from his reputation.

I think this would help to avoid hurried and harmful behaviour from users.

Do you agree?

Comment: General feature-requests/discussions, ... of the network should be posted on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ - the central SE meta site.

Comment: There is no harm with posting feature requests on per site metas, that said, I disagree with this idea (see my post).

Comment: @juergend No, absolutely not. [Posting on a child meta is absolutely fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232).

Answer (score 10):

## No - there should be no punishment for closing questions

Closing a question is a temporary state to **let you know that something is wrong with your post**. Once a question has been closed you should consider the following:

- What was the reason it was closed with?
- What feedback have you received in the comments on your question?
- Is there anything you can do to fix up your post according to [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)
- Is the question even on topic for the site?

While it may be seen as "punishment", that certainly isn't the case. This is in fact the reason that closures go through multiple states. When a question is first closed, it is marked as "on hold" - this is supposed to indicate clearly to the asker that their question is in a limbo state spending edits to fix it up. After a period of time, if the question has remained closed, it will transition into a "closed" state.

During these states, if you edit your question, it will automatically appear in the `/review` "Reopen Votes" queue so that people can vote to reopen it.

Arguing that you believe your question is on topic against the will of the entire community is not going to result in your question being reopened. If you feel that your question was closed incorrectly you can always come to meta and post **one** question asking for clarification so that you can receive a verbose explanation as to why the question was closed.

Comment: The problem I see is not closing a question. The problem is too hurried closing of question whitout specifiyng any reason. And to punish only WRONG close decision. Can you modify your post to answer also these things?

Comment: There is no need, the answers are the same. A reason is specified, it's impossible to close a question without a reason. "Wrong" is subjective, especially when the policies regarding quality levels and scope are still in a state of fluctuation.

Comment: What I'm askying is to help me to avoid errors like the one I've documented (closing question as too broad) would repeat. We can do this improving the guidelines I think (or punishing who votes for close in a too much hurried way).

Comment: The entire Stack Exchange system is voluntary, if you punish people for making judgement calls on particular posts - even if they may be suspect (**and I'm not saying they are in this instance**) you discourage people from taking part and the system fails. Instances like this one need to be dealt with using well understood policies defining the scope of the site and the requirements for posting.

Comment: you are right.. but if you put an excess of rules and people start to close good and constructive question is a bigger issue. I think moderation is an importan part of SE but the fundamental one are the people asking and answering.. We can write down better guidelines to avoid the problem. In this section for example opinionable, and too broad should be more tolerated (let's say not undertolerated as in other sections). How would you solve the issue of "moderator" annoying people asking constructive questions by being closing addicted?

Comment: Sam, since I can't see your original version of the question I can't comment fully, but my understanding is that it took multiple edits to make it acceptable by which time you had gained multiple downvotes, so you deleted it and reposted it. Deleting and reposting a question will result in it getting closed - the "close reason" used is largely irrelevant in that particular situation because you broke the rules by removing a post and reposting an identical post, the fact it later got reopened is irrelevant.

Comment: You're suggesting we make rules to stop people from closing your questions but the reason your question was closed was because you broke the rules, it makes the entire situation a little hard to understand. I have suggested it already but I'm going to suggest it again - [join the Software Recommendations chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) so we can discuss the issues you're having at length and try to resolve them because on meta it seems like we're destined to just go around in circles and not get anywhere.

Comment: @Flyk - None of my questions got closed here... and I fully support the idea that closing a question errorneously should carry a heavy penalty. There are way too many people on this network (not restricted to SR.SE) who close without bothering to consider if THEY are wrong and not the OP - and are wrong. That last comment of yours imputing motivations was way out of line.