# Can we have a migrate to meta.SE off-topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons, migration

[This question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-about-a-reputation-detraction-if-someone-votes-to-close-a-question-and-it-i) seems to request a general SE feature and not just one for SR.

Can we have a new off-topic close reason:

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
>      - meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: [*Please don't migrate low-quality questions to other sites*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites) AKA Don't migrate crap.

Comment: Funny thing: as this is about general SE and not just this site, why this is not posted to meta.stackoverflow.com? :)

Answer (score 6):

SE keeps an eye on metas everywhere, and even if its a general request, its usually fine to leave it on the site meta. There's no practical reason to move it.

Answer (score 4):

When the site enters public beta and gets its own moderators, they will have the ability to migrate posts over to Meta Stack Overflow. In the long run, though, the need for migrating to Meta Stack Overflow is narrow. **General Stack Exchange features are fine to ask on the per-site Meta instead of Meta Stack Overflow**.

The point of having a per-site meta, instead of just one gigantic Meta site for every site (as we had back when we were just a trilogy) is that we want a place for users to be able to report their issues and suggest features while staying within their own community. This way, the environment remains comfortable to them and it's not like walking up to a scary new building that you've never really been to. Not everyone who visits a Stack Exchange site knows that there's Meta Stack Overflow.

When it comes to general Stack Exchange features instead of site-specific features, the site-specific meta is the perfect place to vet out and sort out the details of a given idea or suggestion. The community to which the concern came up often has the clearest idea of why a feature may or may not be necessary. Their discussion in the per-site Meta allows for the kinks to be worked out. If the decision afterwards still isn't solid, then opening a new discussion on Meta Stack Overflow, to open it to the audience of the network as a whole, this works with the extra data gathered by the early discussion. But when these discussions first start, there's no need to open it to everyone at once from the get-go.

We on the Community Team keep an eye on the individual site metas as well as Meta Stack Overflow. As well, the developers monitor bug reports across the network.

Discuss things on your personal meta first. When you feel you want to present the fully fleshed out idea to the network audience to get larger approval, that's when we move things to Meta Stack Overflow. But until that point, there's no need to move anything, and more relevantly anyone.