# What would be our stop gap for other sites to migrate over question?

Tags: discussion, migration

Ok, we know the golden rule of migration:

## Don't migrate crap

Well, there are some questions that meet our (SR) criteria of a good question for recommendation:

- It has requirements
- Correctly scoped
- It won't degenerate into a list
- It's not already a list (preexisting questions)

But, are we going to welcome them? Should we allow those sites to have migration paths (I know that during beta probably we would not have those)? What we will do with those gems of information that nobody likes?

Comment: [*Please don't migrate low-quality questions to other sites*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites) may very well be pertinent as it elaborates quite well on the don't migrate crap rule.

Comment: This may be a bit of a pre-mature discussion. We generally *never* migrate questions to a young beta site. You'd need to be around for a few months before a moderator would even consider sending any sort of question here. Further, you *can't* have a migration path for regular users to a beta site, ever.

Comment: @animuson through I know what you are talking about, but I think that the hidden behaviour is "that other sites will start sending users here"

Answer (score 9):

I see no reason with allowing the site to be used as a migration path for the entire network as required, provided the content that is migrated over here [meets our requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/305) - many of the one to two line questions that get asked on other sites are simply so far off the pace of what we're describing as our quality level that they would just immediately get closed here anyway, and in those cases, the question should be dealt with by the site that it was originally asked on.

**However**, we need the rest of the network to know...

## We are not a dumping ground

Sending high quality questions that are off topic on the site it was asked on but that meet our strict requirements over to us is to be **encouraged**. Migrating bad content that doesn't meet our requirements is *not*.

Answer (score 5):

During the beta phase, fortunately, we won't have any community migration path, only migrations by moderators and reposts.

To all moderators of other Stack Exchange sites, and users who would recommend reposting or migration to Software Recommendations:

We have [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Please:

- **Do not recommend posting on Software Recommendations unless you have read these guidelines.**
- Recommend migrating or reposting on Software Recommendations **only for questions that meet the guidelines**.
- If you do recommend posting on Software Recommendations, be sure to **link to the guidelines**.

In a nutshell, a good recommendation question must have **both a stated purpose and objective requirements**. If a question lacks either element, we don't want it. Additionally, all the usual Stack Exchange rules apply, in particular questions must have *clear* requirements and must not be *too broad*.