# Changed SO response to "recommendation questions"

Tags: feature-request

I posted a request on Meta SO, that questions "closed as a software recommendation" have the closure complaint modified to suggest that SR be used as an alternative.

I'm posting the link here, so that SR-meta people might respond here or at Meta SO as they see fit:  [Changed response to Recommendation questions now that there's a site for them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions)

Comment: It's probably a little early to start making changes like this for a site that has only just entered public beta.

Comment: Definitly agree with @Flyk – and left my comment over there. Even if included at a later time, it should at least include a link to our "quality requirements" ([What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/185)), or we get flooded with questions we had to close straight-away (guaranteed; I've already closed enough of them over at [Android.SE] to know what to expect *just from there*).

Comment: I remember some moderator posting here that the policy is not to move questions from establised sites to beta sites.

Comment: OK, don't move them.  Just say SR exists and add a caveat.  Read my revised question over at SO.

Comment: We're basically saying the same thing on both sites. Since this is an administrative issue for Stack Overflow (and we don't really allow cross-posting), I'm going to close this *here* so not to split up the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I [posted a response to your question on mSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions/222018#222018), as figured I'd leave it here too so that people here can inspect it.

> I really don't know if we should do this. Sure, it'll get us a ton of
>   traffic. But do we *want* that traffic? By the very nature of the site
>   itself, we're not going to be starving of users.
>
> Another thing to consider: SR isn't (and shouldn't be) a 'no-rules
>   shopping site'. We try to keep the questions in as manageable a form
>   as possible. We so far have a *very* small core userbase, and no
>   dedicated diamond mods. I'm not sure we could handle a much bigger
>   flood than we already are.
>
> One more thing: Since we have our rules there, people need to follow
>   them. The people that post recommendation questions on SO **aren't
>   very likely to read our rules either**. That's another thing to
>   consider.
>
> All in all: I don't think we should be pointing people to SR at least
>   until we get our PT mods and we show that we can handle the current
>   flood.

Comment: What makes them more likes to read the rules at the SR site, if they discover it on their own?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying - I'm saying that the people that break the rules on SO aren't the people we want to be inviting here until we get mods, have a strong core userbase, and the capacity to deal with an SO-sized flood. We don't right now.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take things slowly. The site has been public for less than a day. We need the site to grow **gradually**. To accommodate an increasing number of questions, we also need an increasing number of answerers and of janitors.

Our roadmap should look somewhat like this:

- Private beta. Small experiment, establish some basic rules. ([Done](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).)
- Public beta. Let people discover the site naturally. (Just started.)
  Already at this stage, **whenever SR is mentioned, be sure to mention our [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)**.
- Accept moderator-initiated migrations from other Stack Exchange sites. We'll work out a protocol for how moderators (who may not be familiar with SR) should decide when to migrate, based on our experience from the early public beta.
- Progressively start mentioning the site in more and more places. At this stage, I expect that sites such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) (not intended to be an exhaustive list) which currently have a close reason about recommendations will reference our site. The close reason must prominently mention our [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).
- If this site graduates¹, then the aforementioned close reason may turn into a migration target — but only if we have confidence that migrations will tend to be of sufficient quality, which is doubtful.

For the time being, I request that whenever people mention SR.SE, they mention the [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). On Ira's MSO question, I've proposed comment templates to use on SR.SE question candidates and on “Ask on SR” comments that lack a link to the guidelines; SR regulars: please comment on [my MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions/222050#222050) if you disagree wiht my wording.

¹  <sub>“If” rather than “when” not only because this site might fail, but also because it might succeed: if we manage to establish quality guidelines that can be followed on other sites, then SR has no reason to exist and can be folded back into the natural sites.</sub>