# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question

Note: I'm actively working with this user to improve this question. I really feel like there's an on-topic quality question hidden in here. What are we still missing? Or am I way off base and this question isn't appropriate?

---

Final update, I swear (no chameleon questions from me): I feel like we've got this question in a good place, but I'm still waiting before I get confirmation from the community.

---

So, a user who is apparently [question banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225907/software-to-analyze-c-net-code?noredirect=1#comment33747293_22225907) on Software Recs instead asked his question on Stack Overflow (naughty, naughty *finger waggle*). He asked me to ask his question for him here (CW, obviously). I have no problem asking the question for him... **IFF** the question is a good fit for the community. I haven't been that active here so I wanted to check with you guys and gals first. Here's the question in its entirety:

> I'm looking for any software which can:
>
> - analyze .NET source code (c# or vb.net)
> - build some repository which can be queried (NDepend and Resharper do something similar)
> - allow to query this repository looking for classes, methods, calling methods, and so on (like Resharper or NDpend)
> - accessing to the method's name, local variables name, type, static value and also method text
>
> I would like to use it for creating the documentation about the stored
>   procedure called by this software.
>
> ***NDepend*** is a really wonderful tool that analyzes the IL / source code and allows you to write queries like the following one, **but**
>   doesn't provide access to the constant value of the string (I need
>   them to identify the stored procedure name / parameters).
>
> ```
> from m in Types.WithFullNameNotIn( "Core.DbObject").ChildMethods() 
> let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("Core.DbObject")
> where depth0  >= 0 
> && !m.Name.Contains(".ctor")
> orderby depth0
> select new { m, depth0 }
> ```
>
> **What is my final purpose?**
>
> I've got a big source code in Vb.net. I would like to track every call
>   to the stored procedure saving:
>
> The call to the stored procedure behave as it follows:
>
> ```
> RunProcedure("dbo.Log", parameters, "Log_LoadFromID")
> ```
>
> I need to extract:
>
> - the name of the Vb.NET **Method** --> easy using IL and metadata information
> - the name of the **Stored Procedure** --> easy using textual analisys of code
> - the list of the **parameters passed** to the store --> easy using textual analisys of code
>
> I've tried to look for it but I couldn't find anything similar to
>   this.
>
> **Extra details:**
>
> *I think it's really hard to find a similar software. So I've no problem if it's a plugin for Visual Studio as well as a standalone
>   tool or a .NET framework. Also it doesn't matter were this info will
>   be exported. It's only important that I can use this info. I need to
>   generate a report. For sure, I guess, it will be a Windows Software or
>   a .NET Framework, but if you find an Android App doing this it will be
>   ok as well :-)*

Comment: Did you read [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/743/226) and [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). As it's right now it could be closed on sight.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. I wasn't about to copy-paste a question from a banned user without double checking.

Answer (score 3):

Ask this question here if it interests you. Don't feel obliged to post on behalf of someone else. Especially someone who's been suspended — that should be a red flag.

I invite you to read our [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), if you care. If you don't care, just stop wasting your time.

Comment: I'm not invested in this because of this (or any) user. I'm invested in this because I feel like this is potentially a question that could *add value* to the Stack Exchange network. If it results in a quality question with answers, then that's enough for me. From what I've read, this question seems to fit the requirements.

Comment: FWIW, I just helped the user clarify their question, and they were very willing to work on its quality. And if a problematic user learns something about what SE is and how it works, then all the better. I fail to see how this is not a net gain for the network as a whole.