# How is the best way to ask about comparison of Code Generator tools?

Tags: support

I've been suspend here twice, so now I would put the maximum effort in opening a really good question. And I would really appreciate for you advice and help. Please, be batient with me..

I've made some initial search. I've found:

- Visual Studio's T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) -  Check out Scott Hanselman's article for an introduction
- Codesmyth
- http://www.metadrone.com/
- http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx
- http://plinqo.com/
- Codesmith 2.6 is freeware - http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware.aspx

I've found that Codesmith is not a mature product as I would like to.

But how should I open the question? How should I set it? The real question is: "which is the most mature code generator tool?"

Ok, I can workaround it. I can explain deeply why Codesmith is not completely a mature software. **Would it be sufficient for opening a good quality question?**

Comment: Rather than saying why Codesmith is not mature, focus on what your ideal tool would have, that would make your ideal tool mature

Comment: Did the question ever get asked? I would be interested in the answer

Comment: @Mawg: i fear, at the end, I didn't ask or at least I cannot find it on SE https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/103/revious?tab=questions, sorry..

Answer (score 4):

An outline of what makes a good question is here:  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Try reformatting like this.

I need a ________ tool.  [fill in the functionality you are looking for]

I need this tool to be able to: [specific requirements]

1. x
2. y
3. z

It needs to be able to run on: [OS is generally mandatory info, plus pertinent hardware/software restrictions or integrations]

1. OS
2. Pertinent Hardware Restriction
3. Pertinent Software Restriction

I have tried/looked at:  [if you have ruled out some options already, list them, and why, it helps clarify your question]