# Are "Name the program showed in this screenshot" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, screenshots

E.g. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11492/903. On-topic or off-topic?

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen this one!

Answer (score 5):

According to [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) it lacks details. This site is about recommending specific software for specific needs. "Looks nice" might be an acceptable criterium *in context* – but if it's just "an editor that looks nice", it's clearly "too broad".

So unless accompanied by specific requirements, I'd say it doesn't fit [the scope of our site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (a page unfortunately lacking details understandable to new users).

Moreover, just a picture as description will hardly be found by anyone looking for similar software – so it's at least questionable if the resulting answer(s) will be of any "future use" (i.e. will be found at all).

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic.

I don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but IMO such a question isn't asking for software to perform a certain task, and kills our open-ended anything-that-works model.