# How to handle dreamware requests?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I haven't been around Software Recommendations for very long, but I notice a lot of requests never getting answers, or being for software yet to be developed or envisioned, i.e. dreamware.

How does the community handle or propose to handle all these requests?

Comment: [Impossible/impractical requests?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/696/impossible-impractical-requests)

Answer (score 8):

Since we [require a large amount of information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) in questions for them to be acceptable here, it makes sense that many questions would be unanswered. Often, software that does exactly what people need simply doesn't exist.

If a question is low-quality for one reason or another, we should close it. Otherwise, I'd say we should just leave it alone. There's nothing *bad* about having unanswered questions, and software might exist in the future that answers the question. If someone makes that software, we can go back and add an answer to the question.

Comment: Say the question is otherwise good and meeting requirements, should one comment if you happen to know that the combination of software is  not currently available, or likely not to exist?

Comment: Theres IMHO a line to draw between "unlikely to (yet) exist" and "unlikely to be *achievable/possible*". If I ask for a software to predict the future with 100% accuracy, this software does not yet exist and is very unlikely to exist in (predictable) future, so it's a nonsense question even if formally fitting (as per the definition Undo linked: all requirements etc. named). And I'd say *such* a question should be closed/removed as well: low brain quality :)