# Community Promotion Ad on WordPress Development SE? (2015)

Tags: discussion, advertising

In the comments to a Meta discussion on WordPress Development, Rarst (moderator) [suggested](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/4075#comment5903_4075) that we could submit a Community Promotion Ad for Software Recommendations SE.

Their current year’s post is there:
https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/community-promotion-ads-2015

I think their site would be a great place to attract WordPress experts.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no graphic design skills. Can someone come up with an advertisement?

I think it would make sense for the ad(s) to focus on

- recommending WordPress on [cms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms) questions, and/or
- recommending WordPress tools/plugins on [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) questions, and/or
- getting recommendations for WordPress tools/plugins.

(If this works, we could consider doing this for the other SE sites about CMS, too.)

Comment: And the ad should link to [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) or [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Comment: @Gilles: Ads can only link to a single page, if I understand correctly. Do you mean creating a landing page for that ad, which would contain these two links?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul No, an extra level of indirection would just about guarantee that nobody would read them. Ads targeted at askers should link to the question FAQ, ads targeted at answerers should link to the answer FAQ.

Comment: @Gilles: An admin at WordPress said "It seems confusing that this is pointing to a (large) meta thread rather than just stack itself"... you might want to explain your reasoning over there, personally I don't mind either way.

Answer (score 5):

It won't win me a design award, but here you go:

https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4076/81911 (please upvote until it reaches 6 if you are OK with the ad, thanks!)

I just reused our usual ad, with the text "*Looking for a WordPress plugin that fits your very specific needs?*"

I linked to [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) but I feel we could have a "How to ask a good WordPress question?".