# Site software - is it covered?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is 'Software Recommendations' the right place to ask for the most appropriate software when it comes to back-end scripts/software?

For example asking for a CRM that had certain features, or the best PHP script for a given scenario?

Answer (score 2):

As all SE sites, SR is the wrong site to ask for "simply the best". It is however the right place if you explicitly specify your requirements – see: [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

So asking for a CRM with "certain features" is fine as long it's not too broad (it would e.g. be insufficient if those "certain features" would be only "manages a company's interactions with customers and prospects", as that's what a [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) generally does. You must be specific.

Same for the PHP script, but with that even more: A PHP script that "adds 1+1" is quite specific – but for obvious reasons also quite off-topic ;) And again: "the best" is not accepted as criterion here, as it's much too subjective ("one mans owl is another mans nightingale").

Comment: I've modified my question.

Comment: So your question is rather in the context of [Can I ask for help to develop a solution in this site?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2438/185)

Comment: Yes,  with specific needs.  I realise best is subjective and didn't think it through

Comment: Yupp, got that :) Many fall for this, so we're already used to. Especially with the PHP script part, I guess the linked question should match yours. As for the CRM, my answer should still fit: CRM is a complete system, so as long as your question holds "enough information" it should be fine. Scripts are somehow borderline, so it's hard to give generic advice on them.