# Request for new cycling tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Gidday all - I'm a regular on http://bicycling.stackexchange.com/ and we occasionally get questions about software for riding, whether it be mapping or routing or statistics-gathering.

And while they're definitely questions about **cycling**, they're not really about bicycles, so its not really on-topic.  Honestly its a grey area.

We only became aware of this stack today, so in the future will redirect software questions over this way where software questions are clearly on-topic.

Is that acceptable?   If so, might I request a tag be created for each of Bicycling, biking, cycling, cycles and linked together as synonyms ?

Comment: Agreeing with Nicolas here: Would you then setup a tag-wiki for this to make clear what it's about? :)

Answer (score 6):

[cycling](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycling) sounds like a good tag.

As I said [over there](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1108/611), be sure to explain:

- Your final goal
- All of your requirements
- Your operating system (ex: Android)
- Whether it must be able to work offline or not
- Your budget/license requirements (ex: free open source)

Also see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Questions that are too broad (ex: What app can show a map?) get closed, so be sure to add enough requirements.

Comment: On Android.SE we've got a nice Meta-post we redirect to: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) Might be an idea to do it that way as well. The pro is: instead of "skipping the help page and asking straight away", one gets to read at least the outline before finding the link to ask :)