# My question was deleted because it asked how much I should pay for SEO

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It's not spam to ask about a specific delivery. Some moderator was just bullshitting that I was guilty of "spam" just because I asked how much I should pay for SEO.

Can't you speak of economics or business without getting into threats of deleting plain simple questions?

Comment: That "bullshitting" moderator was me – and if you read my comment again you see I was not saying it *is* guilty of spam, but "it might be seen as spam" (promoting that URL). As Journeyman correctly pointed out below, this site is recommending *software,* not services (which is why your question was closed, and its repost as well).

Answer (score 5):

I voted to close [that question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34344/want-to-buy-seo) and its still there (unless you reasked it) . Your question is *still there* as far as I can tell. I do admit, SEO has a terrible reputation since most practitioners of said dark art that you *notice* are spammers.

That said, I VTCed cause I felt it was off topic. Its in no way a software recommendation - you're trying to find someone to do a service for you. It dosen't even fall under the potential grey areas for what's on topic.

If I felt it *was* on topic, the biggest risk I'd see is attracting spammy answers, and someone might protect it. Its *not* on topic as far as I'm concerned.

I'd also like to say while I *was* a moderator once, and that gives me an insight into many of the site's quirks, my actions are as a high rep user.

Assuming it was my downvote, it might be nice to not *assume* the reasons people have, and try to understand the site better. I hope my answer helped there. The tone of this question seems arguementitive. It might be better to ask future questions in a somewhat calmer more measured manner.

Comment: Can't you speak of business here at all???

Comment: "Its in no way a software recommendation"  - its off topic cause of that. This question would be somewhat akin to asking for a good plumber on the site. Its business too.

Comment: This site is not about businesses, but about software :) So I fully agree with Journeyman here (+1 to his answer and comment).

Comment: If I link to somebody, why would that be spam? all I did was asking about SEO market. You are not mature.

Comment: Erm You're entirely ignoring that its off topic. And personal attacks arn't nice.

Answer (score 3):

Journeyman is exactly right. Your question could've been closed, in my eyes, for quite a few reasons. The question is so short I can paste it right here,

> **Want to buy SEO**
>
> I want to buy search engine optimization for a US audience. Can you recommend what I should buy? I have a webapp that I want to promote.

1. **The title**: "*I want to buy SEO*". Wonderful, happy to hear it. Now this relates to software how? Also, a little bit more information would help too, even in a title.
2. **Sentence 1**: "*I want to buy search engine optimization for a US audience.*" Nice to hear. You are aware that **SEO is a process**, not software right?
3. **Sentence 2**: "*Can you recommend what I should buy?*" An SEO specialist? A web marketing company? Not sure if those are software...
4. **Sentence 3**: "*I have a webapp that I want to promote.*" This may have been the only reference to software in this entire question, and it really has nothing to do with the question.

Nowhere did you mention the OS it needs to be compatible on and no budget was given (SEO tools can get really expensive).

Personally, and I have a bit experience on this site, this is how I could see this question be closed:

1. **off-topic** Has nothing to do with software. See the title of this site for more information on that.
2. **Unclear what you're asking** You want to buy SEO, so you want to buy the process of affecting the visibility of a website? And all you give us is US audience and it's for a webapp. Kind of need a bit more than that to give decent answers.
3. **Too broad** Assuming you're looking for software, are you aware of how many SEO tools are out there? Searching for "SEO Software" in google gives over 2.9 million results.
4. **Very Low Quality** Honestly, I don't think you could've taken any less time creating this question. The body of the question seems like only 2 sentences as the 2nd sentence is kind of unnecessary.

So, after writing this masterpiece, you have the nerve to call the actions of a mod BS'ing **and** a retired mod unmatured? Wow.

Before asking another question (even if you disagree with the mods on this site, the actions of what this person did, and the answers presented here), please read the [Tour of this site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) and our [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/133).