# What to do with the closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

What should be done with closed posts?

One of my questions on **Software Recommendations SE** was closed as off-topic.

My [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/can-normalizr-js-library-be-used-without-redux-js-or-flux-js-in-react-js) there is:

> > I want to get rid of the *nested structured*, *denormalized* data responses from my http server it gets from my database server (Postgresql) and its intentionaly *normalized* design data model by me.
>
> I use *React.js* in the front end, web browser.
>
> In [their Github repository](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr), **normalizr.js** library they state:
>
> > Normalizes deeply nested JSON API responses according to a schema for Flux and Redux apps.
>
> Is it possible to use `normalizr` without Redux or Flux with React.js?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Software Recommendations:), it seems your question isn't asking for recommendations on software - kind of necessary here, and so that's why it was closed for being off-topic.

You can do one of three things with closed questions:

1. Simply leave the question be and possibly ask for a migration of the question to another StackExchange site where it would be on-topic.
2. Restate your question to ask for software recommendations. If you'd like to go this route: please check out [the tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site and our [Question Quality Guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/133). Always be clear with your question and include your goal(s) and requirements of the software.
3. Delete or walk away from it. If you want it gone, go ahead and delete it - it's your call. If you want it to stay or want to come back to it later, leave it. It may eventually be deleted by some higher reputable users or moderators on the site but you have time now to do 1. and 2. if you want.

Comment: Should I delete it? and under what conditions? If none of the two is not done, should it be left there?

Comment: You don't have to delete unless you want to, it's really up to you. If you want, again you can restate your question asking for software that can "get rid of the nested structured, denormalized data responses" and for instance state requirements like "must be able to run without Redux or Flux with React.js" and so on. If you just want to forget about the question, forget about it. If you find another SE site it'd be a good fit on, ask for a migration. If you do want to delete, go right ahead. It's your question without any answers - you have full control.

Comment: Does that question here fit here well, as it seems it is the first time this is asked here?

Comment: I see you've just made an edit, let me take a look

Comment: Yes, but I had meant the above comment for this meta question.

Comment: @Işık ok, as to your original question, it's off-topic so not really. While it is the first time being asked (from what I can see), it doesn't belong on the site for software recommendations. The edit to your last question made it more on-topic but it may appear to be a little unclear to what you're asking. Could you provide an example response from the server (if it's not too long) and talk about what you're trying to extract from it? What does normalized design data model look like in this case?