# Are mobile app recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to find out if there exists an Android app to perform a specific function.

Would this be off-topic here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not at all, Android apps are software for phones. These types of questions are on topic at Software Recommendations. Please make sure your question meets the [Question Quality Guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/133) and use the [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) tag if applicable.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but I've been berated by downvotes whenever I dared to assume such axioms in the past. Thanks for your answer, and here's to hoping everyone else on the main site things along the same lines.

Comment: It's great that you asked, @Hashim. Always better to be safe, and it gives us good signal on what information the help center needs to contain.