# Custom close reasons for software recommendations

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Due to the unique nature of Software Recommendations in comparison to the rest of the Stack Exchange network, I feel some discussion needs to go into the creation of close reasons specific to this site.

## What is the point of this post?

The issues I want to tackle with this discussion are as follows:

- Closure reasons should not be intimidating to new users
- People see "on hold" and this scares them, we want our on hold reasons to help them progress their question to a point where it meets our quality requirements
- We want the community consensuses we reach on meta during this beta phase (and in future) to be readily available so people can see why we reached that decision

## What makes a good close reason?

- Clear and concise text that advises the asker what to do next
- Links to meta posts containing guidelines on quality and acceptable subjects
- Links to meta discussions detailing why we reached those particular consensuses

## How should this post be used?

The format I would suggest this discussion takes place in is as follows;

- One close reason per answer
- Votes against the close reason indicate the popularity of that suggestion with the community
- Suggestions and discussions per close reason occurs in the comments below that close reason
- Improvements should be made to existing close reason suggestions rather than submitting multiple similar close reasons

Comment: It's a bit early to do a poll on close reasons. This calls more for discussion at this point. My first instict is: one for lacks a purpose; one for lacks specific requirements or not enough requirements; one for not software as we define it.

Comment: Very well - we can leave this here until more consensus has been reached as to what is actually on and off topic. The framework is in place to deal with it once the time arrives.

Comment: I totally agree: "Closure reasons should not be intimidating to new users" Martin Fowler wrote a book about over commitment in the usage of Patterns. Sometimes peoples forgot to ask: "is my ideological purpose useful for the thing I'm doing?" In my opinion we should ABSOLUTELY avoid over commitment on the rules. There aren't universally good rules. We should evaluate and ask ourselves if the rules are good for this specific section or for that specific question.

Answer (score 13):

This question appears to be off-topic because **it does not contain enough information to give good recommendations**. In particular, questions without **a clear outline of features requested** are off-topic for this site. For more guidelines on what your question should contain, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336)

Comment: Perhaps "This question does not contain enough information to answer it or does not meet our minimum quality requirements. For guidelines on what your question should contain, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336)"

Comment: Rewrote to adapt after "`This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem`" on [so].

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16206295#16206295

Comment: Or, in short: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." That's our "too broad" close-reason, which matches the "not enough information".

Answer (score 10):

Questions that solicit **discussion or [feature comparisons](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69) between multiple products** rather than asking for recommendations that fit within our [clearly defined requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) are off-topic for this site. Instead, **describe the exact features you're looking for** in your question.

Comment: See [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question) for details on consensus

Comment: "`This question has been put on hold`" is not necessary. The text "This question appears to be off-topic" already appears before the specific reason.

Comment: "Questions that solicits discussions or feature comparisons between multiple products rather than to fit within clearly defined requirements are off topic." link somewhere.

Comment: I think it would be preferable to only have one link in the close reason to avoid clutter. As it stands, two is a bit much. It's better to be concise if and where possible.

Comment: While principially in agreement with @DanteTheEgregore, the "general link" might be "generally included" with all close reasons as kind of a footer. It's title could be re-phrased to "How should a question look like", or "What we consider a good question", *for the close reason message*.

Answer (score 4):

> Requests for hosting providers and services in general, [is outside our scope](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/683/226), through we accept asking for [**applications** hosted in the internet (WebApps).](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/219/226)

Comment: Two questions: **1**. Are hosting and service requests frequent enough to actually warrant a custom close reason? **2**. Is the generic `"This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within the scope defined in the help center."` not already comprehensive enough to cover the service/hosting questions that may arise?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore the problem with that *generic* is that it is too generic, the help center is enourmous and finding what you did wrong instead of being tell upfront is unhelpful in beta stage. There has been enough examples of closures due this reason in previous occasions already ([6 to be exact if you count the one that was deleted](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=host+closed%3Ayes)) so it warrant a custom close reason since others doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm in agreement then, if, at this stage, six questions have already been closed for this same reason. I do still believe we need to better define as a community what exactly is and isn't a service request by our standards.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the latest 50 closed questions (excluding duplicates and already-deleted ones) and tried to classify them according to why they were closed, to see if common patterns emerged.

#### General software usage

Potentially SU/Webapps/Android/Apple/… material, but usually too low-quality to migrate.

- [How to exclude directory from Sublime Text search?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17348/how-to-exclude-directory-from-sublime-text-search)
- [how to share device between two or three machines](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/how-to-share-device-between-two-or-three-machines)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/adding-form-to-wix-com-site
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19548/preview-html-plugin

#### General programming

Potentially SO or Programmers material, but usually too low-quality to migrate.

- [Should I use a CSS grid system for this template?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/should-i-use-a-css-grid-system-for-this-template)
- [application with different instances](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17588/application-with-different-instances)
- [Tool to help Understand Disorganized, Very Unconventional and Legacy Code - Temporary](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18490/tool-to-help-understand-disorganized-very-unconventional-and-legacy-code-temp)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19284/linkedin-api-for-company-search-in-ruby

#### Looking for where to download

- [As of April 2015, what is the oldest working version of skype, and where can it be downloaded?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18675/as-of-april-2015-what-is-the-oldest-working-version-of-skype-and-where-can-it)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505/installing-spice3f5-circuit-simulator-on-mac-osx
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/iis-express-10-0-installer

#### Programming language

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19320/which-programming-lanugage-multi-platform

#### Hosting

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/hosting-storage-provider-with-online-file-storage-where-you-can-order-backup-on

#### Service

None. (I was a bit surprised, I thought this was more common, but it turns out that this is one of these cases that aren't easy to determine, but don't come up often.)

(Post-scriptum: [one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19839/currency-converter-that-works-with-a-single-form-field) just turned up, and I missed a specific close reason.)

#### Data or data source

- [Looking for consumable data sets for Soccer (Football) statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18169/looking-for-consumable-data-sets-for-soccer-football-statistics)
- [What are some of the best examples of lock free practices in Java?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19028/what-are-some-of-the-best-examples-of-lock-free-practices-in-java)

#### Hardware

None.

#### Just… what?

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19266/can-you-please-tell-me-ideas-of-a-website-or-an-app-that-you-want-to-be-invented
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19324/jdeveloper-system-requirments
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/what-are-some-promising-databases-coming-out-and-being-researched

#### Too vague/broad/unclear

Questions that are looking for software recommendations (so not off-topic), but lack essential requirements (e.g. operating system), are too vague, are unclear, etc.

- [Javascript coverage with source maps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/javascript-coverage-with-source-maps)
- [Create ISO image file from my CD/DVD optical disc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17134/create-iso-image-file-from-my-cd-dvd-optical-disc)
- [Free CSS3 Editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/free-css3-editor)
- [Web-app to tell me what time a site is most active at?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17288/web-app-to-tell-me-what-time-a-site-is-most-active-at)
- [WebApp with filtering, searching, tagging and social aspect](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17372/webapp-with-filtering-searching-tagging-and-social-aspect)
- [PC / Windows transfer solutions that offer unlimited migrations for restoring data, settings and applications?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17448/pc-windows-transfer-solutions-that-offer-unlimited-migrations-for-restoring-da)
- [Library to build c# webphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/library-to-build-c-webphone)
- [What is important questions when evaluating and purchasing Software Systems?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/what-is-important-questions-when-evaluating-and-purchasing-software-systems)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17523/tool-for-internal-project-management
- [Palette Software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17570/palette-software)
- [Virtual Stock Market](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/virtual-stock-market)
- [Good-looking PuTTY alternative](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/good-looking-putty-alternative)
- [Web-based KML filtering and export project - GIS server required?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17847/web-based-kml-filtering-and-export-project-gis-server-required)
- [Real Time (<10ms response) Graphing/Charting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/real-time-10ms-response-graphing-charting)
- [Screen recording for programming course screencasts](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18272/screen-recording-for-programming-course-screencasts)
- [How to generate System Architecture from java code?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18493/how-to-generate-system-architecture-from-java-code)
- [Linux music server player for YouTube playlists with remote control](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18543/linux-music-server-player-for-youtube-playlists-with-remote-control)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18548/write-html-using-java
- [Note taking app for mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18677/note-taking-app-for-mac)
- [Upload ipython notebook directly to github](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18793/upload-ipython-notebook-directly-to-github)
- [What's the Apache OFbiz PHP or Python alternatives?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18825/whats-the-apache-ofbiz-php-or-python-alternatives)
- [Traktor: show mp3's bpm id3 tag without importing to collection](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18851/traktor-show-mp3s-bpm-id3-tag-without-importing-to-collection)
- [How to mount raw HDD image on Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18966/how-to-mount-raw-hdd-image-on-windows)
- [Software development MANAGEMENT tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18971/software-development-management-tools)
- [an offline iOS app that keeps me busy for 20 minutes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/an-offline-ios-app-that-keeps-me-busy-for-20-minutes)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/js-library-for-easy-building-of-guis-with-knobs-dials-like-panels-in-labview
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19153/which-package-for-creating-tables-via-r
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19174/undervolting-intel-core-i3-on-nvidia-geforce-laptop
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/setting-up-your-own-git-server
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19331/python-soap-library-for-ws-security
- [What's the Parallel (virtual Machine) alternative for windows 8.1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/whats-the-parallel-virtual-machine-alternative-for-windows-8-1)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17435/how-to-provide-sip-protocol-between-server-and-mobile-phones

---

Only 18 questions fall under the “off-topic” heading, and there isn't a big bucket among there that seems to me to warrant a site-specific off-topic reason. I would like to have a custom reason that links to the [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), but unfortunately [this is not possible](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/allow-per-site-close-reasons-that-are-not-off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Questions that ask for **hardware shopping recommendations** are off-topic for this site because they are often only relevant to the question asker **at the time the question was posted** and **age rapidly**. Instead, **state the hardware you already have** along with your software feature requirement outline. For details, please see [Are hardware recommendations on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/317)

Comment: This close reason is for questions that ask for "What is the best hardware to run this specific software?" I predict that we'll have at least one such question during the life of this site.

Comment: While I agree hardware-shopping questions are off-topic, the more important reason to this is the answers are outdated too quickly.

Comment: Decision: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/112/are-hardware-recommendations-on-topic

Comment: In other words, this basically instructs users to change their questions from "What is the best HW to run this specific SW" to "What is the best alternative to SW that runs on this specific HW?" which is on-topic.

Comment: no. This site is about *software*, not about "alternatives to software". It's neither about "alternatives to", but about "software to solve a specific problem".

Comment: @Izzy Software alternatives are permitted as long as the OP specifies exactly what are the features he wants and what the software does. Then he can say that "in other words, I want a good alternative to [software he knows] that can run on my [low-end hardware]". Or should I roll it back?

Comment: I donno, we could just hit it with a generic OT or custom close reason. This in effect means "OP is too dumb to read the name of the site"

Answer (score -1):

This question is not about software recommendations, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Covers everything else not already covered here. Adapted after "`This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.`" on [su].

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Far too generic – and besides, this 1) is the default close-reason already established, 2) your link goes to the wrong page, 3) if it would point to the right one: that's exactly our current problem. There is no real definition (yet). // NOTE: Downvotes on Meta are just saying "I disagree". They do not necessarily mean "low quality", just "different opinion".

Comment: @Izzy "*Why the downvote?*" means "Why the dissenting opinion?". But you've answered that question now.

Comment: @Izzy Actually, looking further into it, I posted this answer back before there was a "Blatantly off-topic" option. But if this is too broad, why did [su] go with it?

Comment: No idea. I'm still missing custom close reasons – and even more I miss what we say is "outlined in our help-center". The latter place we should urgently fill; to me that hint almost feels like a farce.