# How should we deal with question asking for a "project-like"(full system) software

Tags: discussion, questions, policy

Question asking for a software with such specific elements and business rules, like the one asked by @Chris where he ask for [tours booking portal](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/tours-booking-portal).

That is one Portal (as himself states), with specific rules and requirements. in my opinion this is as @James said in his comment:

> Yeah I have to agree, this isn't an application, this is a full system
>   with many apps...this is a company potentially –  James

And also as @danijelc said:

> This kind of software are usually build from scratch.. Since most of
>   such operational software have really specific requirements – 
>   danijelc

We are not a SE for Freelancing projects. And this looks like a software for a company to build, since this need very specific requirements and business rules. With customer personal needs.

I flagged (since I can't vote yet) for the closure of the question as "`too broad`", because I couldn't find a better way to explain this.

I even checked on meta and only could find the question [Custom close reasons for software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/custom-close-reasons-for-software-recommendations) to help me with the option of the close vote.

Comment: It's rather "too narrow" than "too broad". I tend to agree this most likely requires a "custom build", but I wouldn't say that makes it off-topic. OP has to be aware chances on an answer are low – or has to accept a "no, there's no such thing". Still, who knows: there might be something *close* to it, which can be made "completely fit" with minor adjustments.

Comment: There used to be a "too localized" close reason but it was ditched last year.

Comment: I think it's more like a "primary opinion" than "too localized"