# Allow per-site close reasons that are not off-topic

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

[About 2/3 of the questions that we close are due to a lack of clear requirements or purpose](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/custom-close-reasons-for-software-recommendations/1205#1205). Ideally, we would have a close reason that states something like

> Questions must describe the purpose for which the software will be used (what are you trying to accomplish?) and state clear requirements (what features do you need?).
>   For more information, please read our [guidelines for high-quality questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

We can define per-site close reasons, but only under the heading “off-topic”. This is not applicable to our main reason for closing questions: they're on-topic, but too vague or too broad.

Please allow defining custom close reasons under headings other than “off-topic”. Either at the top level or under “too broad” would do for us.

Comment: A bunch of the sites have this same issue. Some sites have a "homework" reason, SO has one for not having code in the question, etc. It might work to just rename off-topic to something else, if we can come up with a good name.

Comment: @Undo I know, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-have-custom-close-reasons) is the request on the main meta, which has been blissfully ignored by Stack Exchange.